# Backpack Laravel - Add 'options' to checklist_dependency field

Tags: laravel-backpack

I want to limit the Roles field depending on the current user's role. Here is my code:

```
CRUD::addField(
            [
                // two interconnected entities
                'label'             => trans('backpack::permissionmanager.user_role_permission'),
                'field_unique_name' => 'user_role_permission',
                'type'              => 'checklist_dependency',
                'name'              => 'roles,permissions',
                'subfields'         => [
                    'primary' => [
                        'label'            => trans('backpack::permissionmanager.roles'),
                        'name'             => 'roles', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
                        'entity'           => 'roles', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
                        'entity_secondary' => 'permissions', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
                        'attribute'        => 'name', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
                        'model'            => config('permission.models.role'), // foreign key model
                        'pivot'            => true, // on create&update, do you need to add/delete pivot table entries?]
                        'number_columns'   => 3, //can be 1,2,3,4,6
                        'options'         => [
                            'label' => function($value){
                                if (backpack_user()->hasRole('Super Admin')) {
                                    return $value->name == 'Super Admin' ? '' : $value->name;
                                } else if (backpack_user()->hasRole('Admin')) {
                                    return $value->name == 'Super Admin' || $value->name == 'Admin' ? '' : $value->name;
                                } else if (backpack_user()->hasRole('Manager')) {
                                    return $value->name == 'Super Admin' || $value->name == 'Admin' || $value->name == 'Manager' ? '' : $value->name;
                                } else {
                                    return $value->name == 'Super Admin' || $value->name == 'Admin' || $value->name == 'Manager' || $value->name == 'Staff' ? '' : $value->name;
                                }

                            },
                            'value' => function($value){
                                if (backpack_user()->hasRole('Super Admin')) {
                                    return $value->name == 'Super Admin' ? '' : $value->name;
                                } else if (backpack_user()->hasRole('Admin')) {
                                    return $value->name == 'Super Admin' || $value->name == 'Admin' ? '' : $value->name;
                                } else if (backpack_user()->hasRole('Manager')) {
                                    return $value->name == 'Super Admin' || $value->name == 'Admin' || $value->name == 'Manager' ? '' : $value->name;
                                } else {
                                    return $value->name == 'Super Admin' || $value->name == 'Admin' || $value->name == 'Manager' || $value->name == 'Staff' ? '' : $value->name;
                                }
                            }
                        ], // options for the 'entity' checkbox list
                    ],
                    'secondary' => [
                        'label'          => mb_ucfirst(trans('backpack::permissionmanager.permission_plural')),
                        'name'           => 'permissions', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
                        'entity'         => 'permissions', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
                        'entity_primary' => 'roles', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
                        'attribute'      => 'name', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
                        'model'          => config('permission.models.permission'), // foreign key model
                        'pivot'          => true, // on create&update, do you need to add/delete pivot table entries?]
                        'number_columns' => 3, //can be 1,2,3,4,6
                    ],
                ]
            ]
        );
```

As you can see, I am using the Permissions manager for backpack. But when I added the 'options' attribute, the CheckifAdmin middleware returns an error.

If there is a better way to implement this, please guide me. I'm very new to Backpack.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by creating an array that will hold the `$roles_list` then filtered the model in the `setup()` function:

```
$this->roles_list = array_filter(config('permission.models.role')::all()->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray(), function($value, $key){
        if(backpack_user()->hasRole('Super Admin')){
            return $value;
        } elseif(backpack_user()->hasRole('Admin')){
            return ($value != 'Super Admin' && $value != 'Admin');
        } elseif(backpack_user()->hasRole('Manager')){
            return ($value != 'Super Admin' && $value != 'Admin' && $value != 'Manager');
        }
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
```

Then added the filtered array in the options attribute:

```
options' => function($query) {
                return $this->roles_list;
            },
```